# php stream returns invalid file format

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, stream

I'm using a Bulk SMS API in my work. To send messages I'm using PHP stream, but it always returns **invalid File format** error.
here is my code

```
$smsContent = "mdn,msg \n"
                            . "91xxxxxxxxxxx,This is a test message \n"
                            . "91xxxxxxxxxx,Demo"; 
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
                'method'        => "POST",
                'header'        => "Content-Type: text/html",
                'timeout'       => 60.0,
                'ignore_errors' => true, 
                'content'       => $smsContent
)));
$this->bulk_service_url = 'https://example.com/BulkSMS/BulkFileSMS.jsp?login=xxxx&passwd=xxxx&verison=1.0&sender_id=xxxxxx&msg_type=text&lang_type=0&callback_url='.base_url() . 'API/sendSMSCallback';
$response = trim(file_get_contents($this->bulk_service_url, false, $context));
print_r($response);exit;
```

The `$response` returns array as follows

```
{"result":{"status":{"errorMessage":"invalid File format","errorCode":"701","statusCode":"1"}}}
```

I'm adding details in the documentation of the API

Parameters :

- **login** : 
  login to be entered .
- **passwd** : 
  Password to be entered .
- **version** : 
  1.0
- **sender_id** : 
  Sender id of the message, 6 letter alpha numeric
- **msg_type** : 
  text for ascii text and unicode_text for unicode message
- **callback_url** : 
  optional, where you want to get the report
- **msg** : 
  msg for each numbers.

**The body of the request should be a Comma separated line with the following example.**

mdn,msg
91xxxxxxxx,This is test message
91xxxxxxxx, Testing

incase only mobile numbers, the message ( msg) is given in the post parameter and the body is as follows

mdn
91xxxxxxxx
91xxxxxxxx

**API RESPONSE**

```
`{"result":{"status":{"statusCode":"0"}},"req_id":"d0dd0ce8-dadf-49fd-a49e-9845787e0507"}`
```

statusCode => 0 success
statusCode => 1 Failure
`{"result":{"status":{"errorMessage":"Invalid Password","errorCode":"700","statusCode":"1"}}}`

700- Invalid Password
701-invalid File format
702-Insufficient Credit
801-Internal DB Error
802 - Uknown Error

Comment: `Content-Type: text/html`  need to be `Content-Type: text/plain`. try once and le us know

Comment: @Alive :( still same error

Comment: share the api link so that i can check input resorce code and let you know error

Comment: sorry I cannot share the link. I will add more details to my question

Comment: edited my question with API documentation